# Is the wavelength of light generated through a chemical reaction independent?

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration

The chemical reaction in question is the reaction between Luminol and hydrogen peroxide. Is the wavelength of light generated through this reaction dependent on the concentration of either reactant?

I am inclined to believe that the answer is no but I do not know why. I could not find an experiment that tested this online either and I'm wondering if anyone else tried this. If I do turn out to be correct, what other factors affect the wavelength of the light emitted in this specific reaction (pressure, temperature, etc.)? or is it fixed?

Comment: Since the individual photons emitted are the result of electronic transactions in a specific molecule then only things that affect the structure of that molecule will affect the wavelength.

Comment: If the concentration of the reactants are changed, the light intensity will change, but not the wavelength of the emitted light.

Comment: Generally, absorption and emission spectrum of dissolved substance or intermediate product may change with concentration, directly, or indirectly via higher temperature because of reaction enthalpy. But it would at the best rather slight shift than significant change.

Comment: See the table here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Effect-of-solvent-on-the-maxi-mum-of-the-luminol-chemilumines_tbl3_230011888.

Comment: @EdV, I was exactly thinking the same thing- solvatochromism of luminol in the excited state will slightly change the emission maximum.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yeah, the freely downloadable paper at the link is a bit old, but has useful information. I probably should have given the full reference in my other comment. As for the shifts themselves, I still commit the sin of thinking primarily in terms of wavelengths rather than wavenumbers, but it is simple to translate them via an online converter! ;-)